# Why does the colour of amethyst fade if exposed to too much light?

Tags: mineralogy, minerals, crystals, crystallography

It is well known that the purple hue that is characteristic of the amethyst quartz ($\ce{SiO2}$) will fade if the crystal is exposed to light for a prolonged period of time.  What is the underlying mechanism of this change?

Comment: I feel like this question is better suited to Chemistry.SE. See discussion at http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/164/when-are-questions-about-crystals-on-topic

Comment: "It is well known"... to most people, maybe.  I just learned something new! :)

Comment: @naught101 I agree. Though this phenomenon does occur naturally, it is a set of chemical reactions that is mostly responsible for this.

Comment: @DominatorX please read the accepted answer on that meta question  -mineralogy (which this question fits under) is on topic here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why amethyst loses its colour in sunlight is due in no small part to what impurity in the $\ce{SiO2}$ crystal structure gives the vivid purple and violet tones of amethyst.

According to several sources ([1](http://www.mindat.org/min-198.html)),([2](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4020-2852-6_63)),([3](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10420150.2011.553283#.VJniTWcCA)), the main source of the colour is naturally irradation-borne tetravalent iron $\ce{Fe^{4+}}$, which is formed via naturally occurring gamma radiation altering trivalent iron $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ during crystalisation ([3](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10420150.2011.553283#.VJniTWcCA)).  Other elements exist as impurities but are far less important considerations for the colour produced ([3](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10420150.2011.553283#.VJniTWcCA)).

The tetravalent state of iron is inherently unstable in 'normal' surface conditions and the process is reversible due to prolonged exposure to natural sunlight ([3](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10420150.2011.553283#.VJniTWcCA)).  Some research and experiments have demonstrated that some of the bleaching is caused by the UV portion of sunlight ([4](http://yadda.icm.edu.pl/yadda/element/bwmeta1.element.elsevier-5f6441a0-f3bc-3552-908b-e86ab30abd5d)).

***References***

([1](http://www.mindat.org/min-198.html)) [Amethyst](http://www.mindat.org/min-198.html), *Mindat.org*

([2](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4020-2852-6_63)) Dudushenko et al. 2003, [What Oxidation State of Iron Determines the Amethyst Colour?](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4020-2852-6_63), *ICAME 2003*

([3](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10420150.2011.553283#.VJniTWcCA)) Hatipoğlu et al. 2011, [Spectral, electron microscopic and chemical investigations of gamma-induced purple color zonings in amethyst crystals from the Dursunbey-Balıkesir region of Turkey](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10420150.2011.553283#.VJniTWcCA), *Radiation Effects and Defects in Solids: Incorporating Plasma Science and Plasma Technology*

([4](http://yadda.icm.edu.pl/yadda/element/bwmeta1.element.elsevier-5f6441a0-f3bc-3552-908b-e86ab30abd5d)) Nunes et al. 2013, [Spectroscopic study of natural quartz samples](http://yadda.icm.edu.pl/yadda/element/bwmeta1.element.elsevier-5f6441a0-f3bc-3552-908b-e86ab30abd5d), *Radiation Physics and Chemistry*

Comment: Tetravalent iron! That's new to me.

Comment: If tetravalent iron seems strange to you, try looking at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrate).

Answer (score 4):

The color of a mineral can be caused by a variety of mechanisms. This is also true of amethyst, which is a variety of quartz ($\ce{SiO2}$), and can be found in many colors.

The major factors responsible for the [production of color](http://www.enmu.edu/services/museums/miles-mineral/colors.shtml) in minerals fall into five categories:

1. The presence of an element essential to the mineral composition
2. The presence of a minor chemical impurity
3. Physical defects in the crystal structure
4. The mechanical mixture of very fine impurities
5. The presence of finely-spaced structures in the mineral

See these pages for more information about the [causes of color in minerals](http://minerals.gps.caltech.edu/COLOR_Causes/index.html).

If you search for "Color Centers in Quartz" you will find a large literature on this subject. Some color centers in quartz can be created or destroyed by irradiating crystals with light or X-rays.

The quantitative measurement and study of mineral color is called [Mineral Spectroscopy](http://minerals.gps.caltech.edu/).

Comment: How does this answer the question?