# how best to preserve the color of my amethyst geode?

Tags: geology

Will bright indirect light cause an amethyst crystal to fade?
How about an overhead LED light?
How is best to preserve the color of my amethyst geode?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but unfortunately, your question isn't about Earth Science as defined in the [help center](http://earth.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @Spencer why? Curation of minerals is within the scope of earth science

Comment: [Why does the colour of amethyst fade if exposed to too much light?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/345/why-does-the-colour-of-amethyst-fade-if-exposed-to-too-much-light)